# Dropdown menu - Jquery problems on IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, compatibility-mode

**EDIT:** The code and examples have been changed, see the progress below.

I'm working on a menu that uses Jquery to animate the display of the dropdown/flyout lists.

The idea is, to have a menu that works well without javascript but when it is enabled we can had a bit of flair with Jquery, adding a alternative stylesheet and some animation.

The problem is IE7 and my inability to solve the bug. I've put an [example online](http://uxte.com/test/menu/dropdown_example.html) where you can see the issue. In IE7 the flyout (second-level navigation) does not display when javascript is enabled.

I have test it in IE8 (compatibility mode) and IE7 standalone I haven't had the opportunity to test in a pure IE7, so if any of you guys have it could you have a try and let me know what happens?

Does anybody know what can be the problem?

**Link to the files:** uxte.com/test/menu/

**Link to example:** uxte.com/test/menu/dropdown_example.html

**Jquery code below:**

```
    $( document ).ready (
 function() {

  $('head link#noscript').replaceWith('<link id="script" rel="stylesheet" href="script.css" type="text/css" />');

  /*Menu effects*/

  function showElement( element ) {

   element.css({ 
    'display' : 'block',
    'opacity' : '0'
   });

   // animate opacity to full
   element.stop().animate({opacity: 1},{
    duration: 500
   });

  }

  function hideElement( element ) {

   // animate opacity to nil
   element.stop().animate({opacity: 0},{
    duration: 500,
    complete: function (){ 
     element.css({ 'display' : 'none' });
    }
   });

  }


  $( "div#menu ul li" ).hover (

   function() {

    var ul = $( this ).find( "ul:first" );
    showElement( ul );

   }, 

   function() {

    var ul = $( this ).find( "ul:first" );
    hideElement( ul );
   }
  );

 }
);
```

Comment: whats up with the red background. i am blinded now after 2 minutes.

Comment: Sorry mate, that was there only for testing purposes ;)

Answer (score 1):

gonna go ahead and guess that ie7 does not support opacity.
need to use

```
 filter: alpha(opacity='90')
```

Comment: It does appear to be opacity related.  If you run this script, .third-level menus will show:

$('div#menu ul li').unbind('mouseover mouseout').mouseover(function(){ $(this).find('ul:first').show(); });

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try and let you know what happens. But should the second-level show as it uses opacity as well?

Comment: So it seems it's not related to opacity since Jquery supports it for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reading a little more about the `animate`, `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` and `fadeTo` I understood that I don't need to use filter: alpha for IE as Jquery already supports it.

Knowing that, I made a test using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` ([now online](http://uxte.com/test/menu/dropdown_example.html)) and it works, but there is a problem, if you hover in and out several times it continues repeating the animation. This doesn't happen with `fadeTo` or `animate` since I can add a `stop()` before but it doesn't work on IE7.

This is my present code and below the example with fadeTo that isn't working in IE7.

```
$( document ).ready (
 function() {

  $('head link#noscript').replaceWith('<link id="script" rel="stylesheet" href="script.css" type="text/css" />');


  $( "div#menu ul li" ).hover (

   function() {

    var ul = $( this ).find( "ul:first" );
    ul.fadeIn('normal');

   }, 

   function() {

    var ul = $( this ).find( "ul:first" );
    ul.fadeOut('normal');
   }
  );

 }
);
```

Not working code (on IE7):

```
$( document ).ready (
 function() {

  $('head link#noscript').replaceWith('<link id="script" rel="stylesheet" href="script.css" type="text/css" />');

  /*Menu effects*/

  function showElement( element ) {

   element.css({ 
    'display' : 'block',
    'opacity' : '0'
   });

   // animate opacity to full
   element.stop().fadeTo(500, 1);


  }

  function hideElement( element ) {

   // animate opacity to nil
   function onComplete(){ 
    element.css({ 'display' : 'none' });
   }
   element.stop().fadeTo(500, 0, onComplete);


  }


  $( "div#menu ul li" ).hover (

   function() {

    var ul = $( this ).find( "ul:first" );
    showElement( ul );

   }, 

   function() {

    var ul = $( this ).find( "ul:first" );
    hideElement( ul );
   }
  );

 }
);
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: After a lot of trial and error I'm going to assume it has to do with the way IE7 interprets Jquery. I've finally came up with a working solution but doesn't answer my initial questions. See the next reply for the working example.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a working solution which in the end is better than my original code since this way I can handle the animation timings using the great [hoverIntent](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent) plugin.

```
$( document ).ready (
    function() {

        function overHandler(element) {

                element.fadeIn('normal');

        }

        function outHandler(element) {

                element.fadeOut('normal');

        }


        $( "div#menu ul li" ).hoverIntent({    
            sensitivity: 3,
            interval: 200,
            over: function(){
                overHandler( $( this ).find( "ul:first" ) );
            },
            timeout: 500,
            out: function(){
                outHandler( $( this ).find( "ul:first" ) );
            }
        });

    }
);
```

**You can see the working example at**: uxte.com/test/menu/dropdown_example.html